# ASP.NET html element tr lost

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

I made script for generate table rows and columns depend on data count. Then I made script :

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            sb.Append("");

            sb.Append("var row = document.createElement('TR');");
            sb.Append("var a = '");

            for (int i = 0; i < dataVar.Count; i++)
            {
                Counter = i;

                int fileNo = Convert.ToInt32(dataVar[i].Replace("picUrl", ""));
                string filename = Request.Params["picUrl" + fileNo];

                sb.Append("<tr>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "<img src=\"" + ResolveUrl(filename) + "\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\" />" +
                            "<input type=\"text\" name=\"picUrl" + Counter + "\" id=\"gbr" + Counter + "\" value=\"" + filename + "\" class=\"d-none\" /></td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "<select name=\"resType" + Counter + "\" id=\"resType" + Counter + "\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm\">" +
                            "<option value=\"\">Parkir</option>" +
                            "<option value=\"0\">Other</option>" +
                            "<option value=\"1\">Bensin</option>" +
                            "<option value=\"2\">E-toll</option>" +
                            "<option value=\"3\">Parkir</option>" +
                            "</select>" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount" + Counter + "\" id=\"txtInput" + Counter + "\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm\" /></td>" +
                        "<td><input id=\"Button" + Counter + "\" name=\"button" + Counter + "\" type=\"button\" value=\"Remove\" onclick = \"RemoveFileUpload(this)\" /></td>" +
                    "</tr>");
            }
            sb.Append("';");

            sb.Append("row.innerHTML = a; var s = document.getElementById(\"AddRow\"); s.appendChild(a); counter++; ");

            ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "addRow", sb.ToString(), true);
```

When I display it on browser, some html element close tag disappear (`<img /> become <img>`, `<input /> become <input>`, `</tr>` tag disappear except the last one, etc). Is it bugs or anyone can help me please ?

Comment: Put your original code back if possible. Your current code does not make sense now, it's incomplete.

Comment: can you test the value of "sb.ToString()". If you can put it into the question. Or test for proper html or not.

Comment: @शेखर: I did and test. the sb.ToString() is work for standart HTML.

Comment: First at all, try register part of JS code without appending with stringbuilder (one row with sample data) - you will test if whole registration of JS cause including JS into your HTML and it is correct. Than, if that worked, post generated string from the end of a stringbuilder appending, because it could be broken code, as you said that something disappeared...

Comment: I think the problem might be because createElement is creating a TR tag, then later it's inner HTML is set to a number of rows. Not sure what solution is but it might work with row = document.createElement();

Answer (score 1):

I was working on it when you updated your question, so the code below is from your original question.

I'm thinking that it has to do with the line near the end: `row.innerHTML = a;`. There you are appending all your new rows to another row and you don't have to do that. Just append your variable `a`.

There might be something else, I have to look more when I can.

```
System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
sb.Append("var a = '");

for (int i = 0; i < dataVar.Count; i++)
{
    int fileNo = Convert.ToInt32(dataVar[i].Replace("picUrl", ""));
    string filename = Request.Params["picUrl" + fileNo];

    sb.Append("<tr>" +
        "<td>" +
            "<img src=\"" + ResolveUrl(filename) + "\" width=\"100px\" height=\"100px\" />" +
            "<input type=\"text\" name=\"picUrl" + i + "\" id=\"gbr" + i + "\" value=\"" + filename + "\" class=\"d-none\" /></td>" +
        "<td>" +
            "<select name=\"resType" + i + "\" id=\"resType" + i + "\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm\">" +
            "<option value=\"\">Parkir</option>" +
            "<option value=\"0\">Other</option>" +
            "<option value=\"1\">Bensin</option>" +
            "<option value=\"2\">E-toll</option>" +
            "<option value=\"3\">Parkir</option>" +
            "</select>" +
        "</td>" +
        "<td><input type=\"text\" name=\"amount" + i + "\" id=\"txtInput" + i + "\" class=\"form-control form-control-sm\" /></td>" +
        "<td><input id=\"Button" + i + "\" name=\"button" + i + "\" type=\"button\" value=\"Remove\" onclick = \"RemoveFileUpload(this)\" /></td>" +
    "</tr>");
}

sb.Append("';");

// make sure `s` is the table or tbody. 
sb.Append("var s = document.getElementById(\"AddRow\"); s.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', a);");

ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "addRow", sb.ToString(), true);
```

Comment: I tried your suggetion, and no rows appears in table.

Comment: AppendChild doesn't work with strings, it needs a parameter of type 'Node'. Instead could try s.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', a);

Comment: Yes, `s.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', a);` is the one. *Make sure `s` is the` table` or the `tbody`* if it exists. You shouldn't need the first two 'append' lines, starting with `sb.Append("");`.

Comment: Another thing you might want to look into is `document.createDocumentFragment();`. I've used that in a similar way to what you're doing, but it might not be needed here.

Comment: Another thing you can do is remove `Counter`. It just duplicates `i`, so use `i`. I've updated.

Comment: And there's no reason to update the counter at the end. Removed.